# How to get (not to set) EdgeWeight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The  Combinatorica package function `Edges` is now replaced by `EdgeList`.
Using Edges one could get the list of edges and corresponding weights as follows: `Edges[g,EdgeWeight]`. Did not work with `EdgeList`. The documentation shows how to set `EdgeWeight` but not how to get it. Is there a way to achieve this with the current functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]`.

Ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphProperties.html